# How to apply .on() method on autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Usually, I use the [autocomplete library](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete) as follow:

```
$('#my_id_element').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({ ...
```

Because the `my_id_element` will be dynamically created, I'll need to bind the autocomplete with using the `.on()` method. I tried it like this:

```
$('#my_id_element').on('autocomplete', function () {
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({...
```

However, this snippet results in the following error message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

and points out to this line:

```
source: function(request, response) {
```

I checked out all the brackets, but they seem to match, so it likely looks that I apply the `.on()` method incorrectly on `autocomplete`.

How do I bind autocomplete correctly?

**EDIT:** posting the full code here - this one is working, but I stuck at applying the `.on()` method on it:

```
<script>
    $('#my_id_element').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<%= autocomplete_company_name_path %>',
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term : request.term
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        min_length: 3,
        delay: 400,
        select: function(e, ui) {
                console.log(ui.item);
                $("#address").val(ui.item.address);
                $("#city").val(ui.item.city);
                $("#state").val(ui.item.state);
                $("#zip").val(ui.item.zip_code);
                $("#country").val(ui.item.country);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Post the full code, there is obviously a syntax error somewhere.

Comment: @Stuart added the full code, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation and the events section https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-open

```js
var tags = ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"];
$("#autocomplete").on('autocompleteopen', function (event, ui) {
  console.log('test')
}).autocomplete({
  source: function (request, response) {
    var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
    response($.grep(tags, function (item) {
      return matcher.test(item);
    }));
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<label for="autocomplete">Select a programming language: </label>
<input id="autocomplete">
```